# What exactly is the difference between field and ring homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between ring homomorphisms and field homomorphisms. Both seem to have similar definitions, i.e., preservation of addition, multiplication, and the multiplicative identity.

Say, is every *ring homomorphism* between two fields $F$ and $K$, automatically a *field homomorphism* or is some extra condition required?

Comment: Yes, a ring homomorphism betwen fieles is always a field homomorphism

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer Oh, I see. Thanks! Suppose $F$ is a field while $K$ is a ring. And $f$ is a ring homomorphism from $F$ to $K$. Then $f(F)$ is a field, right? (Although the whole of $K$ may not be a field and every element in $K$ may not have an inverse element.)

Comment: Yeah, for proving this you just only have to check that the elements have inverses, which is very easy from the properties of homomorphism.

Comment: Actually, it is just a ring homomorphism, since every field is a ring. So it is just a special situation with a special ring, which is a field. So instead of "field homomorphism" one could just say ring homomorphism between fields.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta A small correction: If $f$ is a ring homomorphism from $F$ to $K$, where $F$ is a field and $K$ is a **nonzero** ring, then $f(F)$ is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a field homomorphism is simply a ring homomorphism between fields.